# Swift 3 segment view error

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, swift3

I have a segment control created programmatically in my RegisterViewController. The registerbutton works and saves everything in a Firebase database but when I switch to the loginbutton, the height of the different textfields is changed but the first one doesn't disappear... There's still a small piece of text visible from the first textfield (as you can see on the picture). Furthermore, when I test the login-function, it doesn't log me in as an existing user but it creates a new user in the database, so I guess it doesn't change the code either...

**Login View:**

[image: Login View]

**Register View:**

[image: Register View]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    let inputsContainerView: UIView = {
        let View = UIView()
        View.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        View.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        View.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        View.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return View
    }()

    lazy var loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 101/255, blue: 161/255, alpha: 1)
        button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button

    }()

    func handleLoginRegister() {
        if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            handleLogin()
        } else {
            handleRegister()
        }
    }

    func handleLogin() {
            guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text
                else {
                    print("Form is not valid")
                    return
            }

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return
            }

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }

    func handleRegister() {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text
        else {
            print("Form is not valid")
            return
        }

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return
            }

            guard let uid = user?.uid else {
                return
            }

            //Succesfully authenticated user

            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://assemble-148108.firebaseio.com/")
            let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
            let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
            usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                if err != nil {
                    print(err ?? "")
                    return
                }
                print("Saved user successfully into Firebase db")
            })
        })
    }

    let nameTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Name"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return tf
    }()

    let nameSeparatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 220/225, green: 220/225, blue: 220/225, alpha: 1)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let emailTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Email"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()

    let emailSeparatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 220/225, green: 220/225, blue: 220/225, alpha: 1)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Password"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()

    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return imageView
    }()

     lazy var loginRegisterSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
        return sc
    }()

    func handleLoginRegisterChange() {
        let title = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        loginRegisterButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

        // change height of inputContainerView, but how???
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.constant = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 100 : 150

        // change height of nameTextField
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 0 : 1/3)
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor = emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 1/2 : 1/3)
        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 1/2 : 1/3)
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 61/225, green: 91/255, blue: 151/255, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)
        view.addSubview(loginRegisterButton)
        view.addSubview(profileImageView)
        view.addSubview(loginRegisterSegmentedControl)

        setupInputsContainerView()
        setuploginRegisterButton()
        setupProfileImageView()
        setupRegisterSegmentedControl()

    }
    //hier moet de kleur van de tijd helemaal bovenaan aangepast worden van zwart naar wit
    //override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
      //  return .lightContent
    //}

    func setupRegisterSegmentedControl() {
        // need x, y, width, height constraints

        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:inputsContainerView.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true

    }

    func setupProfileImageView() {
        // need x, y, width, height constraints

        profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    }

    var inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var nameTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var emailTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    func setupInputsContainerView() {
        // need x, y, width, height constraints

        inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor = inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        inputsContainerView.addSubview(nameTextField)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(nameSeparatorView)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(emailTextField)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(emailSeparatorView)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(passwordTextField)

        // need x, y, width, height constraints

        nameTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        nameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        nameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

         // need x, y, width, height constraints
        nameSeparatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        // need x, y, width, height constraints

        emailTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        emailTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        emailTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor = emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true


        // need x, y, width, height constraints
        emailSeparatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true


        // need x, y, width, height constraints

        passwordTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

    }

    func setuploginRegisterButton() {
        // need x, y, width, height constraints
        loginRegisterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix, you set the `nameTextField` to be hidden

```
if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    nameTextField.isHidden = true
} else {
    nameTextField.isHidden = false
}
```

Do this in the `func handleLoginRegisterChange()`.

Also you don't need `func handleLoginRegister()`, it doesn't seem to be used.

If you want a proper fix, when you switch segments, you should remove the name label and redo the constraints.

Comment: thank you for the layout problem, that one is solved right now. Have you any idea why the func handleLoginRegister() don't work? I think if this one works, the loginproblem will be solved as well.

Comment: `handleLoginRegister` is not actually set anywhere. Do you need it?